# Oracle APEX 5: AVG in SubTotal

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, average, oracle-apex-5, rollup

Using Oracle APEX 5 classic report:
How do I get the average of a column in the subtotal line?

I've read that a "simple" rollup function with an aggregate function for columns should do the trick - can someone please clearly describe how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a classic report or interactive report?

Interactive Report:
     Use Actions Menu -> Select Format -> Aggregate -> Function = Average, then select your column.  You also need to have aggregate enabled for the column you need to average (located in column attributes)

Classic Report:
     In the specific Column attributes, I believe you can choose to calculate the average.

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm using a classic report in APEX 5 - in the attributes I only see a field called Compute Sum (ON/OFF).